# Why/Where is calibre writing author/title in metadata when saving to device?

Tags: calibre, nook, metadata

When I connect my device Simple Touch Nook, I send a book to my device using the calibre management software. Although I have the template {title} - {authors} set for sending to device, when I open the Library in the Nook (now unplugged from my computer), I found {authors}/{title} as the title of the book.

I don't know why/where is calibre doing this. It's not documented, not defined and not wanted.

I want to have {title} as the title of my book in Nook's library.

Comment: Where have you set the template {title} - {authors}?

Comment: @Sekhemty In calibre's preferences for transfering ebooks to device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had trouble with metadata from Calibre until I realised that I had to either reconvert or polish the ebook after making any changes to the title, author, description etc.

For the metadata to "stick" you have to polish (in the case of an epub) or convert (in the case of a new book in other than epub format).

Although the metadata will look fine in Calibre, if you've made changes you need to polish or convert for the changes to be applied to the ebook.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, @Azza, but thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Calibre writes the metadata in a seperate file `metadata.opf`. This file looks very much like the `content.opf` file found in an EPUB file, but is different and also exists and has the same format, when your ebooks are not in EPUB format.

The `metadata.opf` filecalib resides in the same directory as the book in your library, easily accessed by right-clicking the book in Calibre and then "Open containing folder"

Polishing the ebook updates the metadata in the file from the `metadata.opf`. However I cannot recommend indiscriminate polishing of all the Ebooks. Mostly because the files date-time-stamp change, even if the metadata was not updated, resulting in a resynchronisation of all the file; but also because it takes more time than necessary and can cause notification overload in the system.

My self answered question [How can I keep a large number of EPUB files, managed in calibre, “polished”](https://ebooks.stackexchange.com/q/423/60) describes a solution for only updating those Ebooks whose metadata are out of date, and in parallel. I use that before every synchronisation, it works within a second for the 2200+ ebooks I have, because most of them don't change from sync to sync.